# DHT11 shows 0 at temp and humidity

Tags: c++, arduino

DHT sensor readings 0 at temperature and humidity in serial monitor (on lcd too, ofc)
Sensor is working, no errors in IDE
Using DHT11 with 3pins
Arduino UNO
LCD and Potentiometer on breadboard

There is my code :
`

```cpp
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Arduino.h> 
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 7
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2, ct = 9;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

int t;
int h;

void setup() {

  lcd.begin(16,2);
  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int h = dht.readHumidity();
  int t = dht.readTemperature();
  delay(2000);
}

 void loop() { 
  
  delay(2000);

 Serial.print("Temperature: ");
 Serial.print(t);
 Serial.print(" *C, ");
 Serial.print("Humidity: ");
 Serial.print(h);
 Serial.println(" %");

 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Temp: ");
 lcd.print(t);
 lcd.print((char)223); 
 lcd.print("C");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Humidity: ");
 lcd.print(h);
 lcd.print("%");
  
 delay(2000);
}
```

////////////////

Comment: You never write to the globals `t` and `h`... (since in `setup()`, you shadow them by identically named locals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan said in the comment, you did not assign the temperature and humidity into the variables.

In theory, by looking at your code, you should move

```
int h = dht.readHumidity();
int t = dht.readTemperature();
```

inside where you do the loop(). something like:

```
 void loop() { 
  
     h = dht.readHumidity();
     t = dht.readTemperature();

     delay(2000);

     Serial.print("Temperature: ");
     // Serial print stuff

     lcd.setCursor(0,0);
     // LCD stuff
  
     delay(2000);
}
```